# Uber API client.request_ride method throws error

Tags: python-2.7, uber-api

I am facing and issue while requesting a cab through Uber Api with Python.
These are the steps I have followed :

1. Creating a session with my server_token.
2. Authorizing with my credentials.
3. Got authorization_url and user authentication is done.
4. Created an object with a session I got from user authentication.
5. Got the credentials using the method :

   credentials = new_session.oauth2credential
6. Estimation for the ride :

   estimate = client.estimate_ride(product_id=PRODUCT_ID,
   start_latitude=xx.xxx, start_longitude=xx.xxx, end_latitude=xx.xxx, end_longitude=xx.xxx)
7. Fetching fare Amount :

   fare = estimate.json.get('fare')
8. I try to request a ride with below code and get the exception :

   response = client.request_ride(product_id=Product_ID,
   start_latitude=xx.xxx, start_longitude=xx.xxx, end_latitude=xx.xxx, end_longitude=xx.xxx, fare_id=fare.get('fare_id'))
9. Exception :

   ClientError: 401: This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: request.delegate.tos_accept, request, request.delegate

Please let me know where am I going wrong. Did I miss any step ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you need to add the 'request' privileged scope when creating the token.

```
from uber_rides.auth import AuthorizationCodeGrant
auth_flow = AuthorizationCodeGrant(
    <CLIENT_ID>,
    <SCOPES>,
    <CLIENT_SECRET>,
    <REDIRECT_URI>
)
auth_url = auth_flow.get_authorization_url()
```

See more details in the [python ride requests tutorial](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/pyhon).